# Formulario con multiples pasos no respeta el required

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.baulphp.com/formulario-con-pasos-bootstrap-usando-php-bootstrap/), en el que se muestra un mismo formulario, pero divido en tres pasos:

¿Cómo logro que los `required` del primer paso se respeten?

Que no se pueda hacer clic en `siguiente` (para pasar al 2do paso), sino que valide que están vacíos.

Siguiendo un comentario de la misma publicación, se recomienda hacer el siguiente script:

```
 jQuery(".next").click(function() {
     current_step = jQuery(this).parent();
     var inputs = current_step.find("input")
     var countFails = 0;

     /**aqui busca si hay informacion el validationMesagge, el cual solo esta lleno cuando el campo esta mal diligenciado*/
     for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       if (inputs[i].validationMessage != "Esperalee") {
         countFails++;
       }
     }
     /*solo vamos a pasar al siguiente cuando ningun input tenga error*/
     if (countFails == 0) {
       next_step = jQuery(this).parent().next();
       next_step.show();
       current_step.hide();
       setProgressBar(++current);
     }
   });
```

Pero sigue ignorando los require y sólo se valida al final cuando hago el submit.

Comparto a continuación el snippet ejecutable, por su atención gracias.

```js
jQuery(".next").click(function() {
  current_step = jQuery(this).parent();
  var inputs = current_step.find("input")
  var countFails = 0;

  /**aqui busca si hay informacion el validationMesagge, el cual solo esta lleno cuando el campo esta mal diligenciado*/
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if (inputs[i].validationMessage != "Esperalee") {
      countFails++;
    }
  }
  /*solo vamos a pasar al siguiente cuando ningun input tenga error*/
  if (countFails == 0) {
    next_step = jQuery(this).parent().next();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();
    setProgressBar(++current);
  }
});



/* Script para mostrar u ocultar segun el paso a paso */

$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 1,
    current_step, next_step, steps;
  steps = $("fieldset").length;
  $(".next").click(function() {
    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().next();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();
    setProgressBar(++current);
  });
  $(".previous").click(function() {
    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();
    setProgressBar(--current);
  });
  setProgressBar(current);
  // Change progress bar action
  function setProgressBar(curStep) {
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar")
      .css("width", percent + "%")
      .html(percent + "%");
  }
});
```

```css
#regiration_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Registro de usuarios paso a paso</h1>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>

  <form id="regiration_form" action="action.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <h2>Paso 1: Crear su cuenta</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="data[email]" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="data[password]" class="next btn btn-info" value="Siguiente" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2> Paso 2: Agregar detalles personales</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Nombres</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[fName]" id="fName" placeholder="Nombres" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lName">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[lName]" id="lName" placeholder="Apellidos" required>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previo" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Siguiente" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2>Paso 3: Información de contacto</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mob">Numero Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob" name="data[mob]" placeholder="Numero Celular" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Direccion</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="data[address]" placeholder="Direccion" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previo" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Enviar" id="submit_data" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma en la que puedes lograr lo que te propones es usando la interfaz [*ValidityState*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) para determinar si el elemento de tipo `input` contiene los datos requeridos.

Por ejemplo, para determinar si un elemento con restricción `required` cumple con la misma puedes verificar el estado de `valueMissing` del objeto `validity` del elemento:

```
  document.getElementById('elemento').validity.valueMissing; // true o false
```

el cual devolverá `true` si el elemento contiene algún valor, y `false` en caso contrario.

Si deseamos saber si el elemento cumple todas las restricciones usaremos la propiedad `valid`:

```
document.getElementById('elemento').validity.valid; // true sólo si cumple todas las restricciones
```

Un ejemplo de uso de estas propiedades en tu código sería aplicarlo al manejador de evento del botón `next`, y realizar el cambio a la siguiente vista sólo si los elementos de tipo `input` de la vista actual son válidos:

```js
$(".next").click(function(e) {
  let first_input;
  let second_input;
  switch(current) {
    case 1: // primera vista
      first_input = document.getElementById('email');
      second_input = document.getElementById('password');
      break;
    case 2: // segunda vista
      first_input = document.getElementById('fName');
      second_input = document.getElementById('lName');
      break;
    case 3: // tercera vista
      first_input = document.getElementById('mob');
      second_input = document.getElementById('address');
    default:
      break;
  }
  // Ahora verificamos el estado de los 2 elementos de la vista y
  // pasamos a la siguiente sólo si ambos son válidos
  if(first_input.validity.valid && second_input.validity.valid) {
    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().next();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();
    setProgressBar(++current);
  }
});
```

Esta sería una forma de impedir que se muestre la siguiente vista si la actual no es válida. Falta decidir si mostramos los mensajes adecuados.

También te falta verificar la última vista, ya que no tienes el botón `next` sino que tienes el botón `submit` y por lo visto no realizas la verificación adecuada en el mismo.

Para esto podrías usar el método [`reportValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) del elemento `form`, añadiendo un manejador de evento al botón de `submit`:

```js
// el evento
$('.submit').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // el formulario
  const formulario = document.querySelector('form');
  
  if(formulario.reportValidity()) {
    formulario.requestSubmit();
  }
});
```

El código completo se vería así:

```js
/* Script para mostrar u ocultar segun el paso a paso */

$(document).ready(function() {
  var current = 1,
    current_step, next_step, steps;
  steps = $("fieldset").length;
  $(".next").click(function(e) {
    let first_input;
    let second_input;
    switch (current) {
      case 1:
        first_input = document.getElementById('email');
        second_input = document.getElementById('password');
        break;
      case 2:
        first_input = document.getElementById('fName');
        second_input = document.getElementById('lName');
        break;
      case 3:
        first_input = document.getElementById('mob');
        second_input = document.getElementById('address');
      default:
        break;
    }
    if(first_input.validity.valid && second_input.validity.valid) {
      current_step = $(this).parent();
      next_step = $(this).parent().next();
      next_step.show();
      current_step.hide();
      setProgressBar(++current);
    }
  });

  $(".previous").click(function() {
    current_step = $(this).parent();
    next_step = $(this).parent().prev();
    next_step.show();
    current_step.hide();
    setProgressBar(--current);
  });


  $('.submit').click(function(e) {
    const formulario = document.querySelector('form');
    e.preventDefault();
    if(formulario.reportValidity()) {
      formulario.requestSubmit();
    }
  });

  setProgressBar(current);
  // Change progress bar action
  function setProgressBar(curStep) {
    var percent = parseFloat(100 / steps) * curStep;
    percent = percent.toFixed();
    $(".progress-bar")
      .css("width", percent + "%")
      .html(percent + "%");
  }
});
```

```css
#regiration_form fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h1>Registro de usuarios paso a paso</h1>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>

  <form id="regiration_form" action="action.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <h2>Paso 1: Crear su cuenta</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="data[email]" placeholder="Email" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="data[password]" class="next btn btn-info" value="Siguiente" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2> Paso 2: Agregar detalles personales</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="fName">Nombres</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[fName]" id="fName" placeholder="Nombres" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="lName">Apellidos</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="data[lName]" id="lName" placeholder="Apellidos" required>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previo" />
      <input type="button" name="next" class="next btn btn-info" value="Siguiente" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <h2>Paso 3: Información de contacto</h2>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mob">Numero Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob" name="data[mob]" placeholder="Numero Celular" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Direccion</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="data[address]" placeholder="Direccion" id="address" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous btn btn-default" value="Previo" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit btn btn-success" value="Enviar" id="submit_data" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Mauricio Ud es un crack! Mil gracias por su explicación